# cucumber-jvm does not identify hook at example level / step level

Tags: java, cucumber, hook, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

Cucumber scenario something similar to below executes fine as cucumber feature, but in Junit level it doesn't recognize example level hooks "@loginAsXXAdmin" and "@loginAsYYAdmin"

- Junit 4.11
- Java 1.8

Can someone shed some light pls?

```
@merchantPage
Feature: Merchant_Tests_DataDriven

Background:
Given User successfully navigated to merchant Summary Page

@sanity
Scenario Outline: Verify new merchant account can be created
When user click on New Merchant button and navigates to Merchants Registration Page
And User select the "<division>" division from the dropdown 
@loginAsXXAdmin 
Examples:
| division|
| XX      |     

@loginAsYYAdmin 
Examples:
| division|
| YY      |
```

Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzUSB.png

Comment: Do u mean tags?

Comment: Thanks @Grasshopper. yeah these are rather hooks, loginAsXXAdmin is implemented as below                                                                  
        @Before(value = "@ loginAsXXAdmin", order = 2)
 public static void login_As_XX_Admin() { .........
  ........ }